# Direct Navigation Property in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, navigation-properties

I want to achieve the following:

```
public class A
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<A> As { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public int AID { get; set; }
    public int BID { get; set; }
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

A and B are many many, joined by C. However, C also has some of it's own properties, which is why I need to represent it.

**I want to go from A directly to Bs without having to go through C first. (and from B to As)**

This would be easy if C simply joined A and B without extra properties. But because C has extra properties and I need to represent it, I get the following error.

> Cannot automatically bind the navigation property 'Bs' on entity type 'A' for the entity set or singleton 'A' because there are two or more matching target entity sets or singletons. The matching entity sets or singletons are: B, Bs.

Here is my mapping of it helps ...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<A>()
                .HasMany<B>(x => x.Bs)
                .WithMany(x => x.As)
                .Map(x =>
                    {
                        x.MapLeftKey("a_id");
                        x.MapRightKey("b_id");
                        x.ToTable("c");
                    });
```

Comment: Can you write custom `CConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<C>`?

Comment: @abatishchev I'm not familiar, could you explain?

Comment: See http://www.remondo.net/code-first-fluent-api-entity-type-configuration/, http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entitytypeconfiguration-class.aspx, etc.

Comment: It's either/or. Either you have C in your class model, and you have to collect `A`'s `Bs` through `C`, or you have a pure many to many association and C is not part of the model, and you can't access `OtherProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with `C`, I suggest you change your model as I show below:

```
public class A
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<C> Cs { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<C> Cs { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public int AID { get; set; }
    public virtual A A { get; set; }    
    public int BID { get; set; }
    public virtual B B { get; set; }

    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your `OnModelCreating` method, you could configure two one-to-many relationships between `C` and `A` and `C` and `B` this way:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<C>().HasRequired(c => c.A).WithMany(a => a.Cs).HasForeignKey(c => c.AID);
     modelBuilder.Entity<C>().HasRequired(c => c.B).WithMany(b => b.Cs).HasForeignKey(c => c.BID);
}
```

As you can see, this is at the end a many-to-many relationship, but now you are mapping the junction table too because you need to add some properties on it.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I am aware I can go through C, but I wanted to specifically skip it.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm afraid that is not possible. If you add a new column to junction table you need a new entity instead of direct many to many relation to have access to the new column.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework will only abstract-away the many-to-many join table if you haven't defined it. Since you want to add a property in that join table you (of course) need to define that table. At that point, you need to go through the join table to get your `B`s from an `A` and `A`s from a `B`.

Also, if you use navigation properties in `C`, you don't even need to define the relationship with Fluent API...

```
public class A
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<C> Cs { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<C> Cs { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And if you want to enforce uniqueness...

```
public class C {
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int AID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AID")]
    public virtual A A { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int BID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BID")]
    public virtual B B { get; set; }

    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I am aware I can go through C, but I wanted to specifically skip it.

Comment: How do you imagine that might work? The only way to "skip" a table is to abstract it away in the ORM layer so you don't see it in code. Inherently, you can't access the hidden table in the ORM layer.